Canvas Frame Capture To MP4 - Video Quality
I have been following this demo showing how to convert an animated canvas to MP4. My issue is that the MP4 quality is low.
I've tried other codecs, but have settled on the one below as it has the best (still terrible) quality out of the other codecs I've tried.
    muxerRef.current = new Mp4Muxer.Muxer({
    target: new Mp4Muxer.ArrayBufferTarget(),
    video: {
      codec: "avc",
      width,
      height,
    },
    fastStart: "in-memory",
  });

  videoEncoderRef.current = new VideoEncoder({
    output: (chunk, meta) => {
      console.log(`Encoded chunk of size ${chunk.byteLength} at timestamp ${meta.timestamp}`);
      muxerRef.current.addVideoChunk(chunk, meta);
    },
    error: (e) => console.error("Video encoding error:", e),
  });

videoEncoderRef.current.configure({
    codec: "avc1.640028",
    width,
    height,
    bitrate: 10000000,
    bitrateMode: "constant",
});

I've run it through ffmpeg and got back these logs...
312-a50e5014f2ad299a.js:1 [info] run FS.writeFile tst.mp4 <611642 bytes binary file>
312-a50e5014f2ad299a.js:1 [info] run FS.readdir .
312-a50e5014f2ad299a.js:1 [info] run ffmpeg command: -i tst.mp4 -hide_banner 
312-a50e5014f2ad299a.js:1 [fferr] Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'tst.mp4':
312-a50e5014f2ad299a.js:1 [fferr]   Metadata:
312-a50e5014f2ad299a.js:1 [fferr]     major_brand     : isom
312-a50e5014f2ad299a.js:1 [fferr]     minor_version   : 512
312-a50e5014f2ad299a.js:1 [fferr]     compatible_brands: isomavc1mp41
312-a50e5014f2ad299a.js:1 [fferr]     creation_time   : 2024-05-07T15:39:25.000000Z
312-a50e5014f2ad299a.js:1 [fferr]   Duration: 00:00:09.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 531 kb/s
269-35bf08de9339787a.js:1 0
312-a50e5014f2ad299a.js:1 [fferr]     Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 586x670 [SAR 1:1 DAR 293:335], 530 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 11520 tbn, 23040 tbc (default)
312-a50e5014f2ad299a.js:1 [fferr]     Metadata:
312-a50e5014f2ad299a.js:1 [fferr]       creation_time   : 2024-05-07T15:39:25.000000Z
312-a50e5014f2ad299a.js:1 [fferr]       handler_name    : mp4-muxer-hdlr
312-a50e5014f2ad299a.js:1 [fferr] At least one output file must be specified
312-a50e5014f2ad299a.js:1 [ffout] FFMPEG_END
312-a50e5014f2ad299a.js:1 [info] run FS.readdir .
enter code here


I did not test the shown code but I noticed there is no mention of keyframe so that might cause bad quality pixels in some video frames. Try replacing videoEncoder.encode(frame); with if (frameNumber == 0) { videoEncoder.encode(frame , { keyframe: true } ); } else { videoEncoder.encode(frame); }. Let me know if the visual result is better when the first frame is encoded as a keyframe.
